# Is it possible to control the keyboard type by code ? (android)

Tags: android

Is it possible to control the keyboard type by java android code ?

for example: if flag=1 and the focus on TextView the keyboard will be numeric

and if the flag=0 the keyboard will be alpha numeric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the input type programatically via the [TextView.setInputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29) method

For instance, for a numeric input:

```
textView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
```

Or:

```
textView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
```

for standard text input